# I think I need a loop in an MS Access Query

Tags: sql, loops, ms-access, while-loop

I have a table of login and logout times for users, table looks something like below:

```
| ID | User |    WorkDate    |  Start   |  Finish  |
|  1 | Bill |     07/12/2017 | 09:00:00 | 17:00:00 |
|  2 | John |     07/12/2017 | 09:00:00 | 12:00:00 |
|  3 | John |     07/12/2017 | 12:30:00 | 17:00:00 |
|  4 | Mary |     07/12/2017 | 09:00:00 | 10:00:00 |
|  5 | Mary |     07/12/2017 | 10:10:00 | 12:00:00 |
|  6 | Mary |     07/12/2017 | 12:10:00 | 17:00:00 |
```

I'm running a query to find out the length of the breaks that each user took by running a date diff between the Min of Finish, and Max of Start, then doing some other sums/queries to find out their break length.

This works where i have a maximum of two rows per User per WorkDate, so rows 1,2,3 give me workable data.

Rows 4,5,6 do not.

So long story short, how can i calculate the break times based on the above data in MS Access in a query. I'm assuming i'm going to need some looping statement but have no idea where to begin.

Comment: Why can't you take the total time for each line, then group by `User` and `WorkDate` to get the total minutes for each user/workdate. Then subtract total minutes from 480 (8 hours * 60 minutes). That would give you the break time amount.

Comment: My very first thought. Great minds think alike! And it worked for 8 hour shifts, but some users work longer than 8 hours, And some work less. Only way to work out break length is to add the 'missing' times together,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that comes to mind first.

First query to get the min/max start and end times.
[image]

Second query to calculate the total time worked for each day by using your Min(start time) and max(end time) query.
[image]

Third query to calculate the total time worked for each shift (time difference between start and end times) and then do a daily sum.
[image]

Forth query to calculate the difference between total time from the second query and the total time from the third query. The difference gives you the amount of break time they took.
[image]

If you need additional help, I can provide some screenshots of example queries.

Comment: Please do, i'm out of the office now, but can provide my own screenshots of what i've got, i think i might be halfway towards your suggestion already.

Comment: I added screenshots as requested. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, will try this when i get to the office!